# How to animate angle measurement

Tags: animation, mesh, vertices

I would like to animate the change in the angle between two objects.

Using the MeasureIt add-on, it is possible to measure the angle in mesh defined by 3 vertices. The image below shows the angle measured correctly.

[image: good measurement]

If a modifier is applied to the mesh (hook in this example), causing the angle to change, MeasureIt is not updating.

[image: wrong measurement]

Is there a way to have MeasureIt update after a modifier is applied?

Comment: can't add comment so posting here, were you able to animate the angle measurement? I am also wondering I should go about it.